# не срабатывает функция целиком, хотя по отдельности все работает

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, помогите найти ошибку в вычислении факториала. По условию задачи при num = 0, функция должна выдавать 1.

```
var arr =[];
var result = 0;
function factorialize(num) {
  if (num != 0) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    arr.push(i);
    }
     result = arr.reduce(function(x,y){
        return x*y;
    }); return result;
  } else return 1;  
}
```

Comment: Программа выдает корректные результаты.

Comment: Дак 1 и выдает вроде

Comment: да, но freecodecamp не считает, что задание выполнено правильно. причина не указана. всю башку сломал.

Comment: @AlexandrShmidt вызовите функцию два раза подряд - в башке и прояснится

Comment: @AlexandrShmidt А Вы так и вставляете ее туда? Переместите объявление переменных внутрь функции

Comment: Igor Lut, спасибо, заработало. А почему они должны быть внутри? (я новичок)

Comment: @AlexandrShmidt наверное, Вы переопределяете уже зарезервированные на сайте переменные

Comment: @DogeDev, спасибо за догадку, буду впредь поосторожнее с названиями переменных)))

Answer (score 0):

А так?

```js
function factorialize(num) {
  if (num < 0) 
        return -1;
  else if (num == 0) 
      return 1;
  else {
      return (num * factorialize(num - 1));
  }
}
factorialize(0);
```